# Rstudio docker image stores the data after commit

Tags: docker, rstudio, commit

When I create the image from rocker/rstudio with installed packages it is like 4Gb after commit. But when I run it, work in it, load some data and more packages, then cleared workspace in Rstudio, stopped the container and committed, it is 18Gb. When I rerun the image, all the data I was working on are there, so I suppose it is because the data are stored there.

How to fix it and clean the cache properly before commit the container?

I run the docker image using -d -p -P -v -e options and commit without any additional options.

Comment: Run `docker diff <container>` to see what has not been cleared.

Comment: Thank you! Will explore this.

Comment: `docker commit` isn't really a best practice.  If you actually need an image, the `Dockerfile` system is much more reproducible.  If you actually need 14 GB of data, storing it in a volume or host directory is better (I've had trouble in the past dealing with 1 GB+ Docker image layers).